# Trouble with sql query in access

Tags: sql, windows, ms-access

I made a query that should show me the delay days between some dates, for some reason it doesen't show me anything as i run it.
I have data that satifies the criterias.

```
SELECT JOB.JOB_ID, JOB.CUSTOMER, JOB.COUNTRY, QUOTATION.CLASSIFICATION, 
QUOTATION.INBOX_DATE, QUOTATION.TECH_EVALUATION_DATE, 
QUOTATION.COST_ANALYSIS_DATE, QUOTATION.PRICING_AND_QUOTATION_DATE, 
QUOTATION.OUTBOX_DATE, QUOTATION.INBOX_DELAY, 
QUOTATION.TECH_EVALUATION_DELAY, QUOTATION.COST_ANALYSIS_DELAY, 
QUOTATION.PRICING_AND_QUOTATION_DELAY, 


IIf([INBOX_DATE]=Null And [TECH_EVALUATION_DATE]=Null,0,DateDiff("w", 
[INBOX_DATE],[TECH_EVALUATION_DATE],2)) AS INBOX_DAYS,
IIf(TECH_EVALUATION_DATE=Null And COST_ANALYSIS_DATE=Null,0,DateDiff("w", 
[TECH_EVALUATION_DATE],[COST_ANALYSIS_DATE],2)) AS TECH_EVALUATION_DAYS, 
IIf(COST_ANALYSIS_DATE=Null And 
PRICING_AND_QUOTATION_DATE=Null,0,DateDiff("w",[COST_ANALYSIS_DATE], 
[PRICING_AND_QUOTATION_DATE],2)) AS COSTING_DAYS, 
IIf(PRICING_AND_QUOTATION_DATE=Null And OUTBOX_DATE=Null,0,DateDiff("w", 
[PRICING_AND_QUOTATION_DATE],[OUTBOX_DATE],2)) AS PRICING_DAYS,
IIf([OUTBOX_DATE]=Null And [ORDER].[ORDER_DATE]=Null,0,DateDiff("w", 
[OUTBOX_DATE],[ORDER].[ORDER_DATE],2)) AS OUTBOX_DAYS


FROM (JOB INNER JOIN QUOTATION ON JOB.[JOB_ID] = QUOTATION.[JOB_ID]) INNER 
JOIN [ORDER] ON JOB.JOB_ID = ORDER.JOB_ID
WHERE (((QUOTATION.CLASSIFICATION)="Special") AND 
((Year([QUOTATION.INBOX_DATE]))=Year(Now())) AND 
((Month([QUOTATION.INBOX_DATE]))=Month(Now())-1));
```

Comment: ORDER is a reserved word, so it would be better to do not use it as a table name. If used, all occurrences should be enclosed in square brackets. Your JOIN clause contains not enclosed ORDER. That may help, but I think your data has no records for criteria. Try to simplify WHERE clause and determine what's wrong

Comment: thank you, the inner join bracketing was changed automatically by access when i viewd the design view, so i belive that is not the problem.

Comment: Remove any WHERE condition and try again. Additional suggestions: Replace "=Null" with "Is Null"). When calculating "days", use "d" (not "w") as interval specifier. The criterion for "month" will fail in January, instead check whether Dateadd("m", 1, [QUOTATION.INBOX_DATE]) is in the current year and month.

Comment: Cannot compare anything to Null. http://allenbrowne.com/casu-12.html